# Database Schema Design for different timesheet format

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

Could someone help to understand the efficient way of storing the timesheet data (**Timesheet_Details**)?
The timesheet data can be input in multiple ways

1. Start time and end time (9am to 5 pm)
2. Plain input of hours (8 hours)
3. Input like hours in multiples of 2 (2,4,8)
4. Based on unit like e.g. 1 = full day, 0.5 = half day.

What I have is a master **Timesheet** table which will store the start and end date for the job. But I am confused how to store the timesheet hours against each date.

**Timesheet**

- id
- client_uuid
- user_uuid
- job_uuid
- start_date
- end_date

**Timesheet_Details**

- id
- timesheet_uuid (FK)
- date
- ?
- ?
- ?

Comment: Avoid UUIDs, use simple `AUTO_INCREMENTs.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the timesheet data can be input in multiple ways (the four mentioned). Is it something you need to have in the interface of the application? Is it something you really need to duplicate in the database? What I mean is that even though the user experience that is asked is to be able to enter the time in multiple different ways, it does not need to be stored this way, the data can be transformed in a way that is consistent in the database, and then you would show the format according to the user preferences. You would use some algorithm to transform the data and store it correctly in the database.

For instance, you could add a table that contains all the possible ways of showing the time, listing the four that you mentioned here but with codes, let's name it "time_presentation". The interface would show a dropdown and the user would select a way to enter the time. The interface would change according to what they want (for example, two inputs to enter beginning and end, one input to enter only the hours, etc.). Then, the data would be sent to the backend and stored in the Timesheet_Details table but always with the same format that you will have calculated with the code, for example, a float column containing the total hours, and a column containing a foreign key to the table "time_presentation". Then, to show the item in the interface, you would be able to use both columns and reverse the process to show it according to what the user entered and how they entered it (if it's important the user sees it as entered).

If it's absolutly necessary to store the data directly with the 4 methods mentioned, then I would suggest using a varchar column with the value (but this would be a lot less easy to validate).

Comment: Thanks Lysane Fréchette for your kind suggestion. I like your idea of time_presentation interface.